# .net mvc5 application occasionally crashes with ..ctor reference for no apparent reason while instantiating view model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, crash

This is a question about an occasional crash with a .NET MVC-5 application.

I can perform a particular action in a view which causes a controller to instantiate a view model successfully many times. Then for no apparent reason the app the same action causes a crash with the following text appearing:

> [Null Reference Exception: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object]
>   RotaSystem.ViewModels.DailyViewModel..ctor(FormCollection form) +273
>   RotaSystem.Controllers.DayViewController.SaveAppointment(FormCollection formCollection) +31
>   etc

The controller is passing a form collection to the view model during the instantiation. I have no idea why this happens just occasionally or why it refers to '..ctor' which is shorthand for constructor. How can I stop this from happening.

The app is running on a shared web server. I use Entity Framework with a SQL server instance on another server.

I am interested if anyone else has come across this and if so, what is the solution.

Here is the constructor code:

```
public DailyViewModel(FormCollection form)
    {
        //new or manually edited appointment returned
        errorMsg = "";
        recurSeq = 0;
        recurOrigApId = 0;
        //int recFreqId = Convert.ToInt32(form["appointmentRecurrenceFrequency"]);
        this.recurrenceFrequency = db.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY.Find(Convert.ToInt32(form["appointmentRecurrenceFrequency"]));
        this.editRecs = form["editRecurrences"];

        if (dayViewDate == "" || dayViewDate == null)
        {
            dayViewDate = HttpContext.Current.Session["dayViewDate"].ToString();
        }

        if (form["appointmentId"] == null || form["appointmentId"] == "")
        {
            createAppointment(form);
            if (this.recurrenceFrequency.RF_FREQUENCY > 0)
            {
                addRecurrenceToNewOrEditedAppt();
                createDuplicateAppointment(form);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            editAppointment(form);
            if (editRecs == "y")
            {
                editRecurrences(form);
            }
                    public DailyViewModel()
    {
        // day view navigation item clicked, or redirection from appointment create or change save
        string format = "ddd dd/MM/yyyy";
        DateTime dNow = DateTime.Now;
        dayViewDate = dNow.ToString(format);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["dayViewDate"] = dayViewDate;
        if (initProperties())
        {
            getAppointments();
        }

    }
        }
```

Here is the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAppointment(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        DailyViewModel dvm = new DailyViewModel(formCollection);
        if (dvm.errorMsg == "")
        {
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("../Error", new { errMsg = dvm.errorMsg });
        } 
    }
```

Here is the base constructor:

```
        public DailyViewModel()
    {
        // day view navigation item clicked, or redirection from appointment create or change save
        string format = "ddd dd/MM/yyyy";
        DateTime dNow = DateTime.Now;
        dayViewDate = dNow.ToString(format);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["dayViewDate"] = dayViewDate;
        if (initProperties())
        {
            getAppointments();
        }

    }
```

Comment: some better and clear image??

Comment: @Neel No. No images of errors or code. They're useless when it comes to search-indexing.

Comment: ok @J.Steen then would ask for some extra information!

Comment: What's happening in your DailyViewModel ctor? Put a break-point in there and see if it goes in and what happens there. Also if you have a base view model class, put a breakpoint in the base VM ctor. Alternatively share the code in the ctor?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection by any chance? Could be the DI falling over.

Comment: Sorry this was the first time I tried this. I will quote the error:[Null Reference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] RotaSystem.ViewModels.DailyViewModel..ctor(FormCollection form) +273 RotaSystem.Controllers.DayViewController.SaveAppointment(FormCollection formCollectio) + 31 etc etc

Comment: I will edit my initial question with relevent code

Comment: There is no dependency injection. It is a very rare occurrence and has never occurred in localhost, only on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, I think you'll just need to step through the code and see which reference is null and is causing the exception.

My guess is it's here:

`Convert.ToInt32(form["appointmentRecurrenceFrequency"]));`

and `form["appointmentRecurrenceFrequency"]` is sometimes null.

If you can't debug since it only happens on the live server, add some logging. Log the values of your potential objects causing the NullRef exception. Then deploy it and try replicate. When it breaks, BAM! check the log, find the culprit and you should be golden.

Comment: AppointmentRecurrenceFrequency is a select element with a minimum and default value of 1 = None Selected. Nevertheless its always best to check for null anyway in case the db table from which the select element is constructed was unavailable when the view loaded. I will also add logging as you suggested. Thanks for the suggestions.